# Are Outlook addings installation supported in Outlook desktop clients aside from Outlook for Mac?

Tags: gmail, office-js, outlook-web-app, office-store

I am trying to install our custom adding into a Gmail account synchronized with outlook desktop client for Windows, but we are not getting de option from de app. Switching to another office365 inbox works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature of supporting in-client store in gmail account in Outlook Desktop, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.